# Silverlight RIA Service hosting

Tags: silverlight, web-services, iis-7, ria

I wonder is it possible to host RIA service as a stand alone application in IIS7? I've playing around with some RIA services and a wonder whether this scenario is possible. My goal is to detach the service from the WebSite application and host it separately.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely possible, just create another ASP.Net webforms application, add the domain service, reference your model (if its in another library), and link the Silverlight project to it.  Might also be best to host your XAP in the same project as the RIA service to avoid any cross domain issues.  In your real website, just copy and paste the object tag and javascript it generates and make sure its pointing to the right location on the RIA service site.

Comment: Thanks, this was not exactly what we were looking for, but this will do the job I think.